# "the product of the factors" versus "the factors of the product"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, education

Could somebody please compare and contrast the meanings of the two phrases:

"the product of the factors"

and

"the factors of the product."

In terms of expressing possession. Thank you.

Comment: In what context. please give an example. Multipliation and division in a commutative situation, non-commutative?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The factors  go into the product's construction. Also, the product is the result of an operation on the factors.

The same can be said for a sum and its terms:

The terms go into the sum's construction. Also, the sum is the result of an 
operation on the terms.

Answer (score 6):

The factors $a$, $b$, and $c$ have product $a\cdot b\cdot c$.

$a$, $b$, and $c$ are the **factors of the product** $abc$.

$abc$ is the **product of the factors** $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

I think "the product of the factors" is a value with each factor in the exact expressing possession.And "the factors of the product." is a set of factor values, that means you can express these values in any order.